# Increase performance of my pyspark program for data filter

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to increase the performance of my application using pyspark.

The dataframe is like this: each column represents a comment posted by user XXX for question XXX.

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+

|user_id    | comment_id   |question_id| 

+-----------+--------------+----------+

|   10181831|R2OX4JVN03FOMT|6302014700| 

|   51697036|R1R4GTQCO51GC0|B0000001NY|
```

Now I want to remove comments published by users with less than 1 comments published and reviews from questions with less than 3number of comments received

My code is like this:

```py
window_u = Window.partitionBy("user_id")
window_p = Window.partitionBy("question_id")


reviews = reviews.withColumn("n", 
count("user_id").over(window_u)).filter("n >= 1").drop("n")
reviews = reviews.withColumn("n", 
count("question_id").over(window_p)).filter("n >= 3").drop("n")
```

The problem is that now this application runs very slow since I have a really big datasets. Is there any problem to increase the performance?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly filter out null records for less than 1 records and then run the partition query that will sure run faster than the two partition by queries, and there is a mistake in your query i think you want to count comment_id instead of question_id

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

window_p = Window.partitionBy("question_id")

reviews = reviews.filter(
    F.col("comment_id).isNotNull()
).withColumn(
    "n", 
    F.count("comment_id").over(window_p)
).filter("n >= 3").drop("n")
```

or you can perform groupby operation after filtering out null records first

```
reviews.filter(
        F.col("comment_id).isNotNull()
).groupby(
  "question_id", 
   F.count("comment_id").alias("n")
).filter("n >= 3").drop("n")
```

this will run faster than partition by but you have to join it again with main table if you need all the columns

Comment: groupby and window, which is faster?

Comment: and how to join it back again?

Comment: groupby is faster than windows and you can join it back with main dataframe on groupby keys

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach -

1.Create eligible_user and eligible_questions list based on the desired condition

2.Use `isin()` to filter out users and questions those does not comply with condition.

Here is detailed example:

```
eligible_users = df\
    .groupBy('user_id')\
    .count().\
    filter("count>=1")\
    .select('user_id')\
    .rdd.map(lambda row : row[0])\
    .collect()

eligible_questions = df\
    .groupBy('question_id')\
    .count()\
    .filter("count>=3")\
    .select('question_id')\
    .rdd.map(lambda row : row[0])\
    .collect()

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df\
    .where(col('user_id').isin(eligible_users) & col('question_id').isin(eligible_questions))\
    .show()
```

Comment: will it be faster?